# Flutter : Weird gap between items of ListView

Tags: flutter

I'm having a weird issue with Flutter and the ListView widget. I can see a gap between my items. I can see the black background. Is there something I'm missing so that these gaps does not show? Here is the whole application code:

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() => runApp(new MyApp());

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return new MaterialApp(
      title: 'Flutter Demo',
      home: Container(
        color: Colors.black,
        child: new ListView.builder(
          itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) {
            return new Container(
              color: Colors.pink.shade100,
              child: Container(
                height: 100.0,
              ),
            );
          },
          itemCount: 100,
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Notice how the gaps are not always visible and change while scrolling.
[image: ListView gap issue]

Comment: which version/channel of flutter are you using? did you try on simulator android/ios ?

Comment: I've tried your code - there is no gaps on my device

Comment: - Flutter 0.9.4 • channel beta • https://github.com/flutter/flutter.git
- Framework • revision f37c235c32 (5 weeks ago) • 2018-09-25 17:45:40 -0400
- Engine • revision 74625aed32
- Tools • Dart 2.1.0-dev.5.0.flutter-a2eb050044


I have the same issue on a Pixel 2 XL simulator. The gif is from a Pixel 1

Comment: I tested on a Pixel 3 XL and it does not happen. Only on my PIxel 1 (physical) and Pixel 2 (simulator)

Comment: Same issue with the Pixel 2 emulator on macOS.

Comment: Have you opened an issue with the Flutter team on GitHub?

Comment: Any update on this issue?

Comment: Anyone find a solution on this one?

Answer (score 0):

I tried running your code but I didn't got any unexpected padding between List items. I'm currently on Flutter 2.5

You can try adding padding 0 on your ListView and see if it removes the unexpected padding.

```dart
child: ListView.builder(
  padding: EdgeInsets.all(0.0),
  ...
),
```

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue, where the line would appear on the end of list view thus showing divider in last two Childs of the ListView.
Solutions I tried was :

- setting padding of ListView as zero
- setting addRepaintBoundary as false

> (spoiler alert) both didn't work.

***If all the children of list view are of same color, then wrap you ListView with container and set the color of the container to the color of list child. It will hide the lines.***