# Unwanted gap between items in Listview flutter

Tags: listview, dart, flutter, divider

I have a Listview whose contents are dynamic.
The Listview is used for showing a list of dynamic widgets.
Populated the Listview using the below code

```
new Container(
      color: Colors.white,
      child:
      new ListView(
        padding: EdgeInsets.all(0.0),
        children: _widgetsList.map((Widget item){
          return new Container(
            color: Colors.red,
            child: item,
          );
        }).toList(),
      ),
);
```

And the output is the image below

[image]

The problem is between each items in the listview there appears a very small gap, Which I want to be removed.

[image]

Waiting for your help!

Comment: Similar question, yet to be answered. [Flutter : Weird gap between items of ListView](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53055010/flutter-weird-gap-between-items-of-listview/55117286#55117286)

Comment: `child: item,`: what kind of Widgets are the items in your Listview?

Comment: please add the code of item

Comment: items are custom widgets made.

Comment: Any update on this issue?

Answer (score 3):

Try this

```
class Item extends StatelessWidget {
  const Item({
    Key key,
  }) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Column(children: [
      Text(
    'YOUR TITLE',
    style: TextStyle(fontWeight: FontWeight.bold),
      ),
      Text('youremail@mail.com'),
      Text('Ph. 9494949494949'),
    ]);
  }
}


new Container(
      color: Colors.white,
      child:
      new ListView(
        padding: EdgeInsets.all(0.0),
        children: _widgetsList.map((Widget item){
          return new Container(
            color: Colors.red,
            child: Item(),
          );
        }).toList(),
      ),
);
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems rows of `ListView` are drawn independent of each other, unlike for example rows of a `Column`. Flutter engine tries to draw them as close to each other as possible, but in its final calculations there remains a small fraction of pixels between them, which I suspect may have something to do with *int* to *double* castings, maybe.

In case of `ListView`, one can wrap it inside of an `Container` of course and set the same color for each row and the parent `Container`.

I faced this problem when implementing a list using `SliverListView`, which doesn't let you wrap it in a `Container` or set a general background. Accidentally I found out a workaround which works somehow:

Instead of setting color of the child `Container`, set it on its `decoration` property, and then also set the `border` property of `decoration`. The weird part is, this works even if you set just a vertical border!